# Inserting values in a heatmap plotted using ggplot

Tags: r, heatmap

I have prepared a heatmap using ggplot using following commands:

```
mat_data=read.xlsx("average_trendfollowing.xlsx")
mat_data$Investment.Horizon=factor(mat_data$Investment.Horizon, levels=mat_data$Investment.Horizon)

p <- ggplot(data = mat_data) +                        # Set data
  geom_tile(aes(y = Investment.Horizon, x = Smoothing.Parameter, fill = Annualized.Returns)) +        # Define variables to plot
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "black")

p + ggtitle("Trendfollowing Strategy") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))
```

How do i insert my datapoints of Annualized.Returns into the plots. I used

```
geom_text(aes(fill = mat_data$Annualized.Returns))
```

which I found on net but its not working somehow.

Comment: For starters, don't use `$` inside `aes`. Also, since you have mapped `x` and `y` within `geom_tile`, `geom_text` has no x and y locations. Perhaps try `p + geom_text(aes(y = Investment.Horizon, x = Smoothing.Parameter, label = Annualized.Returns))`

Comment: The clarification is really helpful. Can I control the font size/ color for the inserted values using the same function?